# Report "Queries by type" analysis

Tags: postgresql, pgbadger

I'm using pgbadger to analize postgres logs.
I see "queries by type" section and don't understand what means "others" category in table.

[image: queries by type]

I know only dml, ddl, tcl, dcl commands. DCL is absent in table, but Others is too huge to be only dcl.

Please tell me what queries are included in category "Others"?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is referring to my executed functions, every time a function is executed pgbadger recognize it as "others" and I  have select, create a temp table, insert and delete in one single function. Wondering if triggers can be recognized as "others" as well.